# Suffix removal with setup script doesn't work

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, url, url-rewrite

Method inside InstallData.php/UpgradeData.php to remove suffix from product and catalog pages:

```
public function removeSuffix()
{
    $this->_config->saveConfig('catalog/seo/product_url_suffix', null, 'default', 0);
    $this->_config->saveConfig('catalog/seo/category_url_suffix', null, 'default', 0);
}
```

As you can see in screenshots below, in backend the changes have been made and the `core_config_data` table has the fields that it would have if it was done manually in backend, but in `url_rewrite` table paths don't get updated.

Product and category links still show up as e.g. `http://test.dev/gear/bags.html` with the suffix.

I have done `sudo bin/magento indexer:reindex` and also tried flushing cache.

---

The suffix fields in backend are changed after running script:

[image]

---

The `core_config_data` table has the fields that would normally be there if it was done manually:

[image]

---

The `url_rewrite` table paths are not being changed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

This setup script will set the product and category suffix values to an empty string and will update the url_rewrite table accordingly (assuming the suffix values were not empty to begin with).

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\App\State as AppState;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $configFactory;

    protected $appState;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Factory $configFactory,
        AppState $appState
    ){
        $this->configFactory = $configFactory;
        $this->appState = $appState;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $this->appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

        $config = $this->configFactory->create();
        $config->setDataByPath('catalog/seo/product_url_suffix', '');
        $config->save();

        $config = $this->configFactory->create();
        $config->setDataByPath('catalog/seo/category_url_suffix', '');
        $config->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Original answer:

There is an [afterSave method](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.3/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/System/Config/Backend/Catalog/Url/Rewrite/Suffix.php#L92-L98) that runs when saving those values in the admin. You could try saving the suffix values in the admin in the System Config section of the admin and see if that removes the suffix from the url_rewrite table.

Also note that in Magento 2 there is no longer a url_rewrite index process, so this may have something to do with the index not making any difference.

Comment: Yes, if I manually change them in backend it works, but that's not what I want. I want it to work in the setup script.

Comment: Well, the afterSave method is a public function, so you may be able to call afterSave on the Magento/Catalog/Model/System/Config/Backend/Catalog/Url/Rewrite/Suffix class. You will need to play with changing the value because afterSave checks if the value has changed before calling updateSuffixForUrlRewrites.

Comment: `url_rewrite` table updates request_path if a product/category gets saved. Is there a way I could loop through every product and category and trigger save on them?

Comment: @Rudolph, I have updated my answer. Please give that a try.

Comment: It works, thanks! What does the  setAreaCode() method do in here `$this->_appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');` ?

Comment: @Rudolph, The setAreaCode was needed in order to get the correct Backend Model to load, since the afterSave method only runs in the admin. [This post](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1666/2) does a pretty good job capturing the basics of areas in Magento, and contains links to the Magento documentation on areas.